# snowflake cannot load table : Geography validation failed: Edge crosses edge

Tags: python, geometry, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am trying to access table in snowflake. I' using snowflake connector inside jupyter lab. One of the columns in the table is type geometry (Data type -GEOGRAPHY).
I'm trying to view the table but I get error:

```
select *
from "PORDUCTION"."CGF"."SQUARE_DATA"
```

> Geography validation failed: Edge (-168.751000,-82.520000) --
> (-179.857000,-80.929000) crosses edge (178.971000,-82.430000) --
> (-169.313000,-80.122000)

This eerror appears when I use the connection in jupyter lab notebook and also when I try to open this inside snowflake paltform.
This is the first time I get such an error in snowflake, I didn't know it does some validation to geography data, usually when I have geometry problems I solve them after lodaing the data but here I cannot open it.

**My end goal: to be able to open this table and understand what is the reason for this error.**

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a query with Geospatial data type in Jupyter notebook with Snowflake python connector, it fetched the data successfully without any error.

Example:

```
create table geospatial_table (id integer, g geography);
insert into geospatial_table values
    (1, 'POINT(-122.35 37.55)'), (2, 'LINESTRING(-124.20 42.00, -120.01 41.99)');
```

Now open jupyter notebook , create a connection and select the data from the table geospatial_table

Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import snowflake.connector

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='username',
    password='xxxxx,
    account='xxxxx',
    database='databasename',
    role='rolename',
    schema='schemaname',
    warehouse='warehousename'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    
    cs.execute("SELECT * from 
    geospatial_table")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row)
    
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()

Output: The output in JSON

[(1, '{\n          "coordinates": [\n                    -122.35,\n                    37.55\n          ],\n          "type": "Point"\n}'), 

(2, '{\n          "coordinates": [\n                    [\n                              -124.2,\n                              42\n                    ],\n                    [\n                              -120.01,\n                              41.99\n                    ]\n          ],\n          "type": "LineString"\n}')]
```

Please capture the python connector log and check the error if still doesn't resolve.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#logging) for logs